Set a default for a TypeScript generic Type: unknown vs any
I have an interface that takes a generic type input called Data
export interface MyStructure<Data> {
  id: string;
  data: Data;
}

I would like to make it optional to specify the Data type, allowing to use for example:
function printId(obj: MyStructure): void {
    console.log(obj.id);
}

because for contexts such as printId you do not need to specify the Data generic type of Mystructure<Data>.
I'm wondering what the possibilities are; if I should default it to any or unknown and what would be the difference.
export interface MyStructure<Data = unknown> {
  id: string;
  data: Data;
}

export interface MyStructure<Data = any> {
  id: string;
  data: Data;
}


What's NodeData? Is it a typo or an undeclared type? Either way, please [edit] to make your code a [mre].

ops, bad copy paste from my real-case scenario. I edited it! Indeed it's Data the generic type

Both Data = unknown and Data = any can be used, however there are some important differences:

unknown: Provides better type safety by restricting the operations one can perform on the data property unless its type is explicitly checked first, preventing misuses of that property

any: Allows basically any kind of operation on the data property, potentially resulting in runtime errors.


The best choice would surely be unknown.
export interface MyStructure<Data = unknown> {
  id: string;
  data: Data;
}


This has very little to do with generics. It's just a description of unknown and any. And I'm pretty sure it's far from the first one.

The data property here is independent of Data. It's some other type called NodeData. Is it a typo?

yes, it was a typo. Fixed.
